# Piwik database - piwik_archive_blob value column

Tags: matomo

I am using Piwik and after inspecting the database i see a table: piwik_archive_blob__

This table has a column called value with type: mediumblob

The values appear to be jumbled characters. I assume that there is an encode/decode process.

Can anyone help me decode this column. I think there is good data here, but i need to be able to read it

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to be able to decode and read this value. If it is serialized and then gzcompressed. Cant i just gzuncompress and then deserialize to get the value. I want to be able to get the data in the mysql table without using there reporting api

Comment: Why not use the reporting HTTP API?

Answer (score 1):

The `value` column stores serialized and [gzcompressed](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php) [DataTable](https://github.com/piwik/piwik/blob/master/core/DataTable.php) objects, so there is no easy way to read it.

Comment: Can i just gzuncompress and then deserialize to read the content on the value column? Or is there more to it

Comment: You will have to use PHP to easily read object properties. I don't think it's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick example how you could uncompress and deserialize it using PHP:

1. Download the blob as a .bin using something a tool like phpmyadmin
2. Load the file into PHP, uncompress and unserialze it using the following:

`<?php
    $sBlobFile = file_get_contents( 'piwik_archive_blob_2017_03-value.bin' );
    $sBlobFile = unserialize( gzuncompress ( $sBlobFile ) );
    var_dump( $sBlobFile );`

Of course you can also just retrieve the blob using MySQL and access it directly in PHP opposed to downloading it as a file first.